# I am getting run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set on sheet. Possibly not selecting worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting "run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" when I try to run this code.  the error comes up on line 8.  In my locals window I see:

Expression : Value : Type

LR : 0 : 0

i : 0 : 0

ws : Nothing : Worksheet

So I believe that it is not selecting the worksheet but I may be way off here.
I am new to VBA scripting still so any help would be appreciated!

```
    Sub ConditionalFormat()

    Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet


     With Sheets("Overall Stats").Select
        LR = ws.Range("G3" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Line 8 here
            For i = 1 To LR
                With ws.Range("G" & i)
                   If .Value = "ISO2" Then

                        Range("L3").Select
                        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                        Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3

                        End With
                    End If
                End With
            Next i
        End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments:

- Until a variable is assigned a value, it contains the default. For a long, that's `0`; for a worksheet (or other object) that's `Nothing`.
- Usually, people try to avoid using `.Select` in code, because it slows it down.

  - I also don't know what the code would try to do with this: `With Sheets("Overall Stats").Select`
- When using a `With ws` statement, that means that a line like `ws.Range("A1")` can become `.Range("A1")` instead. **Note:** if you omit the period (i.e. use `Range("A1")`, the code will default to using the designated range from the ActiveWorksheet -- which is not necessarily the one specified in the `With` statement.)

---

See updated code below:

```
Sub ConditionalFormat()

    Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Overall Stats")


    With ws
        LR = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Line 8 here 'removed the `3` from `G3`
        For i = 1 To LR
            With .Range("G" & i)
                If .Value = "ISO2" Then

                    Range(ws.Range("L3"), ws.Range("L3").End(xlDown)).FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3

                    'End With 'This line is extraneous and should be removed. It WILL throw an error, if uncommented.
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @MikeF. I accidentally posted too soon. See my finished answer.

Comment: ok, now it is throwing Run-time error '1004': Method "Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed on line 8 still

Comment: @MikeF. I had accidentally posted my answer in the middle of typing. If you haven't assigned a value to `ws`, it's going to throw an error every time you reference it.

Comment: @MikeF. Sorry, just identified another issue. If you append the total number of rows (i.e. 1000000) to `G3`, it thinks you are trying to reference the range `G31000000` or G-31 Million. which is probably why the range method failed. I corrected my code.

Comment: Yeah, i updated my script to reflect yours.  I have the Set ws = sheets("Overall Stats" and it is grabbing that sheet now.  i am getting a different error now though.